# Why is this Swift code getting errors?

Tags: ios, swift

I am presently working on a first Swift project, and making a newcomer's errors.

The class I am working on is meant to export three of its methods to global variables:

```
var getAngle:[AnyObject]!;
var getHours:[AnyObject]!
var getMinutes:[AnyObject]!;

class GpsViewController : UIViewController {

    // ....

    required init() {
        // super.init();
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        parser.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX");
        parser.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ";
        getAngle = self.restrictToAngle;
        getHours = self.restrictToHours;
        getMinutes = self.restrictToMinutes;
    }

    func getHourAndAngle() { // Hour hand angle in radians from 12 o'clock position, clockwise.
        var now = NSDate();
        var today = now;
        var todayFormatted = this.formatter(today);
        var yesterday = today.dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow(-24 * 60 * 60);
        var yesterdayFormatted = this.formatter(yesterday);
        var tomorrow = today.dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow(24 * 60 * 60);
        var tomorrowFormatted = this.formatter(tomorrow);
        var yesterdaySunset = this.presentLocation[yesterdayFormatted]["sunset"];
        var todaySunrise = this.presentLocation[todayFormatted]["sunrise"];
        var todaySunset = this.presentLocation[todayFormatted]["sunset"];
        var tomorrowSunrise = this.presentLocation[tomorrowFormatted]["sunrise"];

        var duration = 0.0;
        var position = 0.0;
        var startingHour = 18;
        var offset = 0.0;
        if now.isLessThanDate(todaySunrise) {
            length = todaySunrise.timeIntervalSinceDate(yesterdaySunset);
            position = now.timeIntervalSinceDate(yesterdaySunset);
            offset = -0.5;
        } else if now.isLessThanDate(todaySunset) {
            length = todaySunset.timeIntervalSinceDate(todaySunrise);
            position = now.timeIntervalSinceDate(todaySunrise);
            offset = 0.5;
            startingHour = 6;
        } else {
            length = tomorrowSunrise.timeIntervalSinceDate(todaySunset);
            position = now.timeIntervalSinceDate(todaySunset);
            offset = 1.5;
        }
        var proportion = position / length;
        var angle = M_PI + (2 * M_PI * (proportion + offset));
        var hours = floor(24 * 60 * 60 * ((1 + proportion + offset) % 1.0) / (60 * 60));
        var minutes = floor(24 * 60 * 60 * (1 + proportion + offset) % 60 * 60);
        return ["angle": angle, "hour": hour, "minutes": minutes];
    }

    func restrictToHours() {
        return getHoursMinutesAngle["hour"];
    }

    func restrictToAngle() {
        return getHoursMinutesAngle["angle"];
    }

    func restrictToMinutes() {
        return getHoursMinutesAngle["minutes"];
    }

    // ...
}
```

I'm getting several errors, including in init()'s assignment of getAngle, "Value of type GpsViewController has no member restrictToAngle".

Could you tell me what the n00b errors are here?

Comment: At least you have to declare a return type in the 3 functions at the bottom as they clearly return something.

Comment: 1. What is `this`? 2. Your returning methods are missing a return signature. 3. You're assigning methods, not calling them.

Comment: @EricD. maybe it's JavaSwift ;-)

Comment: Yes, it is JavaSwift, and I"m working on knowing how to simply use Swift.

Comment: @EricD. What does an appropriate return signature look like? I looked around and couldn't track it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign a function `self.restrictToAngle` to `getAngle`, a variable of type `[AnyObject]!` (i.e. an array).

Answer (score 1):

As @EricD and others pointed out, there are quite a lot of issues. For understanding how function definition, calls & return type work in swift, check this [Apple documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158).